# how to create same line if else statement around wc -l output

Tags: bash, tcsh

I'm not at all familiar with tcsh, so really hoping someone could drop some knowledge on what i'm missing here. I'm trying to build a single lined if else statement that checks the number of rows in a file, and outputs a touch file if the number of rows > 1. I'm checking if rows is greater than 1 because the file can be generated with just header info. (Separately if anyone has any useful online guides that I may use for all things tcsh, that would also be very helpful)

**Example file 1 (has data):**

title1,title2
data1,data2

**Example file 2 (empty):**

title1,title2

**Expected output:**

If file has data, generates a has_data.txt, else does not generate file

**What I've tried:**

wc -l dummy_file_empty.txt >1 && touch has_data.txt - *does not really evaluate greater than*

**update** `` is used for evaluating statements in line, and $output is an array? So needed to reference index 1 to get the line count

set output=`wc -l dummy_file_empty.txt` | if($output[1] >1) touch has_data.txt - *returns expression syntax error*

if ( wc -l dummy_file_empty.txt ) > 10 touch has_data.txt - *returns expression syntax error*

i can invoke bash shell as-well if a solution exists in bash ( saw examples where bash is piped at the end of statement |bash and tested it to ensure it works on my machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[ $(cat file.txt | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && touch has_data.txt
```

When you use `>` this will attempt to write to a file. In this case a file named `1` or `10`. You want to use `-gt` which stands for greater than.

If you're running this in a `tcsh` terminal, then you can invoke this via bash:

```
bash -c '[[ $(cat file.txt | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && touch has_data.txt'
```

Comment: Giving this a shot!

Comment: This was using `bash`. What was the exact output you received?

Comment: Literally - **Illegal variable name.**
I tried appending bash to the end separated by a pipe (from examples i've seen) and also tried adding it to the begining

Comment: Are you running this within a script, or the terminal? If you're running it straight into the terminal then what's the output of `echo $0`?

Comment: on terminal - result is tcsh, however, I'm able to invoke some bash statements with | bash, just for whatever reason, i'm not able to with your statement

Comment: I have edited the answer for a way to invoke this with a bash shell when using `tcsh`. Try that.

Comment: interesting, why would it not work when appending | bash? Also, if the file does not exist, how do you handle that scenario?

Comment: It does if you `echo '[[ $(cat file.txt | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] && touch has_data.txt' | bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a solution where I've gotten somewhat close..albeit i'm not really able to handle scenarios where the file might not exist. Hopefully somebody has guidance on whether this a good way to do it.

set output=`wc -l file.txt` && if ( $output[1] > 1 ) touch has_data.txt